# ASP.Net Themes, UserControls and CSS

Tags: css, user-controls, asp.net-3.5, themes

I'm building a Web application with rougly 30 pages, 12 user controls and 3 masterpages.
I've centralized all the CSS in a Theme called Default. The application will expand in the near future.

What is a best practice in separating css files?
Should I:

**A** - Put everything in one big CSS file separated by comment sections (every page has all styles)
**B** - Separate the styles per UserControl in a new CSS file (every page has all styles)
**C** - Same as B, but not storing the UserControl CSS files in the Theme (manual css loading in the ascx).
**D** - .......?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend separating your styles out into their various types of elements. Have a style sheet for fonts, another for presentation/layout, another for complex div behavior, then beyond that have individual style sheets for exclusion cases.

Then you could have a global style sheet that imports the defaults for all controls, and the the master pages can determine special cases beyond that. I don't recommend separating out by UserControl though. Right now you have a very limited set. I run a site with almost 200 user controls and 200 style sheets would drive me batty.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of separate css files for your user controls is the ability to use skins. This way you can easily change the styling of your user control by setting `Skin="DarkAndCreepy"` or `Skin="FluffyBunnies"`.

For user controls which are expected to look the same no matter what, you can stick with the main css file.

Answer (score 0):

I've read in other questions on this site that a single file is the way to go.